# How can i achieve this signature?

Tags: transactions, hash, ecdsa

I want to make a signature in bitcoin where the nonce and private are the same. For example, the private key is 0x1000 and the nonce for the R value is also 0x1000

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve this with The secp256k1 calculator.

https://github.com/MrMaxweII/Secp256k1-Calculator

Click on the Sig function from the menu in the middle.

Enter 0x1000 for the h,k, and private key values.

The result will be:
R: 0x175e159f728b865a72f99cc6c6fc846de0b93833fd2222ed73fce5b551e5b739
S: 0x175e159f728b865a72f99cc6c6fc846de0b93833fd2222ed73fce5b551e5b73a
Z: 0x1000

The calculator mentioned works perfect, it is awesome.